# Output Formatting Issue in Python Code for Employee Hierarchy

Tags: python, data-structures, formatting, hierarchy, output-formatting

I'm encountering an issue with the output formatting in my Python code related to displaying the hierarchy of employees in a company. Despite implementing the logic correctly, the output is displaying individual characters instead of complete strings representing employees.

**Here's a brief overview of the problem:**

- I have a Python program that manages employee information within a company.
- One of the functionalities of the program is to display the hierarchy of employees starting from a given manager.
- I'm constructing the hierarchy, but when printing the output, it's showing individual characters instead of complete strings representing employees.
- I've ensured that the code logic for constructing the hierarchy is correct, but there seems to be an issue with how the output is being processed or displayed.

**Here is a sample I/O statement.**

*Sample input:*

EMPLOYEE_HIERARCHY Kevin

*Sample output:*

EMPLOYEE_HIERARCHY :>
Employee [name=Kevin, gender=MALE]
Employee [name=Manurola, gender=FEMALE] Employee [name=Nivan, gender=MALE] Employee [name=Yash, gender=MALE]
Employee [name=Simmy, gender=FEMALE]

*My output:*

EMPLOYEE_HIERARCHY :>
'E'
'm'
'p'
'l'
'o'
'y'
'e'
'e'
' '
'['
'n'
'a'
'm'
'e'
'='
'K'
'e'
'v'
'i'
'n'
','
' '
'g'
'e'
'n'
'd'
'e'
'r'
'='
'G'
'e'
'n'
'd'
'e'
'r'
'.'
'M'
'A'
'L'
'E'
']'
'\n'
' '
' '
'E'
'm'
'p'
'l'
'o'
'y'
'e'
'e'
' '
'['
'n'
'a'
'm'
'e'
'='
'M'
'a'
'n'
'u'
'r'
'o'
'l'
'a'
','
' '
'g'
'e'
'n'
'd'
'e'
'r'
'='
'G'
'e'
'n'
'd'
'e'
'r'
'.'
'F'
'E'
'M'
'A'
'L'
'E'
']'
'\n'
' '
' '
'E'
'm'
'p'
'l'
'o'
'y'
'e'
'e'
' '
'['
'n'
'a'
'm'
'e'
'='
'N'
'i'
'v'
'a'
'n'
','
' '
'g'
'e'
'n'
'd'
'e'
'r'
'='
'G'
'e'
'n'
'd'
'e'
'r'
'.'
'M'
'A'
'L'
'E'
']'
'\n'
' '
' '
' '
' '
'E'
'm'
'p'
'l'
'o'
'y'
'e'
'e'
' '
'['
'n'
'a'
'm'
'e'
'='
'S'
'i'
'm'
'm'
'y'
','
' '
'g'
'e'
'n'
'd'
'e'
'r'
'='
'G'
'e'
'n'
'd'
'e'
'r'
'.'
'F'
'E'
'M'
'A'
'L'
'E'
']'
'\n'
' '
' '
'E'
'm'
'p'
'l'
'o'
'y'
'e'
'e'
' '
'['
'n'
'a'
'm'
'e'
'='
'Y'
'a'
's'
'h'
','
' '
'g'
'e'
'n'
'd'
'e'
'r'
'='
'G'
'e'
'n'
'd'
'e'
'r'
'.'
'M'
'A'
'L'
'E'
']'

This is my implementation:

```
    def get_employee_hierarchy(self, manager_name: str) -> List[str]:
        output_tree = []

        def build_hierarchy(employee_name, level=0):
            employee = self._employee_book.get(employee_name)
            if not employee:
                return []

            indent = "\t" * level
            employee_str = f"{indent}Employee [name={employee.get_name()}, gender={employee.get_gender().value}]"
            hierarchy = [employee_str]

            direct_reports = self.get_direct_reports(employee_name)
            for direct_report in direct_reports:
                hierarchy.extend(build_hierarchy(direct_report.get_name(), level + 1))

            return hierarchy

        hierarchy = build_hierarchy(manager_name)
        output_tree.extend(hierarchy)

        # Join the hierarchy items into a single string with newlines
        output_str = '\n'.join(output_tree)

        return output_str
```

I'm seeking assistance in identifying and resolving this output formatting issue so that the hierarchy of employees can be displayed correctly.

Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There's not enough code here. You need to show more of your class's implementation

Comment: Hi! Imagine I'm trying to run your program and get the same output as you. Currently I cannot do that using just the code that you have pasted in your question. I strongly encourage you to read the [mre] link given by @СергейКох above.